# How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization

So I am trying to run Ubuntu in a virtualbox but on installing 12.10 from the .iso I was greeted by a warning telling me that audio wouldn't work then I pressed next and this popped up:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Tux 3
VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR
(VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED)
Details

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

And then it doesn't work.

I assigned 4GB of my 8GB to Ubuntu, 100 dynamically allocated GB of space, and 12MB of graphics memory. I'm running an Asus p8z77 V LX mobo with an Intel i5 3550 processor.

Downloaded 12.04.2 on my PC and tried again. Still getting the same message.

Comment: Related: [Cannot install Ubuntu in VirtualBox due to " this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot" error](http://askubuntu.com/q/308937)

Answer (score 71):

Before changing BIOS settings we may want to see if hardware virtualization (VT-x for Intel, AMD-V for AMD processors) is supported by our CPU.

From a terminal issue

```bsh
grep --color vmx /proc/cpuinfo ## for an Intel processor
grep --color svm /proc/cpuinfo ## for an AMD processor
```

If virtualization was supported the flag `vmx` (for Intel CPUs) or `svm` (for AMD CPUs) will be colored.

[image]

In case the CPU supports hardware virtualization, we need to enable it in the computer BIOS to be able to use it.

Also read [How to determine if CPU VT extensions are enabled in bios?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103965/how-to-determine-if-cpu-vt-extensions-enabled-in-bios/103966#103966) for other approaches.

Enter the BIOS (often pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> while booting) and see with the manual how it is named there. Each BIOS appears to have a different name fror this. Search for `Virtualization`, `Virtualization Technology (VT-x), SVM, VMX`, or similar, here shown for an Award BIOS:

[image: Award BIOS Virtualization Flag]

For an example screenshot of an Asus EFI-BIOS [see this answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/375351).

Set this entry to `Enabled` in case it was not done yet. Some BIOS need a **cold boot** (i.e. boot from power off state) to be able to use hardware virtualization.

Hardware virtualization can then be chosen in the virtual machine's  *System -> Acceleration* settings:

[image]

By this the VM uses hardware virtualization for optimal performance. We would even be able to run a 64-bit guest OS on a 32-bit host for testing.

Comment: I still get this problem. My 'vmx' is coloured when running the command above and I've gone and enabled 'virtualisation' in the BIOS as well.

Comment: After changing the bios setting to ON, don't just restart your computer, turn it off and then on! Apparently just restart doesn't do the thing :/

Comment: In my case 'vmx' was colored. But when I checked BIOS 'virtualisation' wasn't enabled. So it seems checking terminal command suggested by Takkat isn't a confirmation that 'virtualisation' is enabled.

Comment: @KaushikAcharya: thank you for pointing this out.. The terminal commands for CPU flags were suggested by an edit from another user. I admit I had not tested them thoroughly - my bad. Nevertheless they are useful to see whether the CPU in our system does support virtualization at all.

Comment: See more details on distinguishing cpu support from bios support via th `kvm-ok` command in the `qemu-kvm` package.  Read more at http://askubuntu.com/questions/103965/how-to-determine-if-cpu-vt-extensions-enabled-in-bios/103966#103966

Comment: Just in case anyone has an HP computer, VT-x is in BIOS/Security/System Security.

Comment: @BorisChurzin solution actually worked - the computer must have to be firstly completely turned off/shut down after saving the bios settings

Comment: @jave.web: thanks for the feedback - I edited this into the answer as it appears to affect many people.

Comment: `sudo grep --color vmx /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact error, and fixed it by dropping the 4095 GB to 3072 MB (3 GB). This is because it was 32-bit. I think the more than 3 GB is throwing it off.

Comment: I had the same experience - despite the articles I was finding saying that the BIOS needs to be modified, the issue apparently lied in that I tried upping the memory for the virtual machine and it apparently was more than the 32-bit system could handle.