# Virtualbox - Failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, virtualization

I installed VirtualBox via Software Center. When I try to load a VM, getting an error exactly like this:

[image: Error window]

After I googled this error, found many different solutions, none of them were helped my situation. Also I removed all packages associated with VirtualBox, then downloaded and installed the *latest package which I downloaded from Oracle* repositories. Nothing is changed.

**Additional Information:**

- OS   : Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
- VM   : Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon/MATE 64-bit

I created new `vdi` disk and tried to start it from `.iso` image.

**Virtualbox Settings:**

- Num of processors : 4
- Memory : 512 MB
- Video Memory : 128 MB
- 3D Acceleration: Enabled

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. The VM you are trying to start needs hardware virtualization enabled. See the follwing Q&A on how to do so (provided your CPU is capable of this):

- [How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)

If this does not resolve the issue, the following steps may help:

- Reboot the host OS
- Try with fewer virtual CPUs starting from 1 only
- *disable* VT-x settings in VBoxManager (reported to worked but I doubt this)
- on a Hewlett Packard machine hardware VT-x could only be achieved with a BIOS update ([source superuser.com](https://superuser.com/q/463523))

Comment: it's already enabled.

Comment: Please add this valuable information to your question. In addition we also may need to know the architecture of host and guest and where the VM you try to start comes from.

Comment: ok, edited question; more information is added..

Answer (score 0):

Click **"Discard"** (Discard the saved state) option (option from the virtual box manager) and try starting the virtual box once again it must work . this usually happens when your host operating system sleeps while your virtual machine is still active . Please note any unsaved data will be lost .

Answer (score -2):

Yes, for me that was the issue. Run the VB as an administrator. Right click on the VB, and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: That looks like a Windows "solution" - in any case **never** run VirtualBox (or VMWare) as root/administrator.

Answer (score -3):

It's that you need to run Virtualbox as an administrator.

Comment: **Never** run virtualbox/vmware as root!