# Virtualbox VT-x is not available

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox

So I had virtual box working perfectly before I decided to do a complete system wipe recently. Upon re-installing a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 13.04 and running a full upgrade, I attempted to set my virtualbox up again; however when ever I try to start my VM, I receive the following error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.
VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).
Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

I'm using the OSE version from the Ubuntu Software Center.
I also tried the PUEL edition from oracle's website, no luck.

Any help?

Comment: Is VT-x enabled in your machine's BIOS?

Comment: I can't find the option in my BIOS.

Comment: see e.g.: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox it may have different names though.

Comment: get in touch with system manufacturer/ motherboard manufacturer's web site /google for bios manual. .. It should be physical hardware bios related.. you have to enable all necessary featuresfrom bios  for  virtual box to work with vt ..  Its different from pc model to model .. for example see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/607897/no-option-for-64-bit-os-virtualbox-guest-os-in-ubuntu-14-10-dell-optiplex-755

Comment: I found a solution in a [forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=58820#), but i don't know if it works; try to type the following command
`VBoxManage modifyvm <vmname> --longmode off` where `<vmname>` is your virtual machine name