# No option for 64-bit OS VirtualBox guest OS in Ubuntu 14.10 Dell OptiPlex 755

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

I have a Ubuntu desktop installed on [Dell Optiplex 755](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_OptiPlex#Models.2C_in_relative_chronological_order). It's my regular desktop, and I installed Oracle [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads. The version selected was the "Ubuntu 13.04 ("Raring") / 13.10 ("Saucy") / 14.04 ("Trusty") / 14.10 ("Utopic")" AMD64 one.

And my OS is also 64 bit...:

```
uname -a
Linux mydd 3.16.0-29-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 15 22:27:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I believe my processor is 64-bit capable and my motherboard has enabled vt settings.... This is my processor information from the `lscpu` command:

[image]

I believe I don't have VM products such as [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine), and I tried searching VM products using lsmod .. (just googled and found):

```
lsmod | grep vm
lsmod | grep kvm
```

Both are having blank results...

Yet, I can't find 64-bit version of guest VM settings...

[image]

I tried installing/reinstalling .. yet not working.. Why can't I install a 64-bit guest vms on my PC? What should I chang to get the 64-bit OS working on my current PC/PS using VirtualBox? Any settings I should change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the BIOS I had to change the following settings

```
Security > Execute Disable (set to On)
Performance > Virtualization (set to On)
Performance > VT for Direct I/O Access (set to On)
Performance > Trusted Execution (set to Off)
```

In my case first 3 i have already turned on, and what i had to turn off was Performance > Trusted Execution

Thanks to the article that pinpoited exact issue with bios on dell optiplex755 http://lifeofageekadmin.com/enable-virtualization-on-dell-optiplex-755-to-run-oracle-virtualbox-4/

Now everything is ok

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Enable **Intel (R) Virtualization Technology** and **Intel (R) VT-d Feature** in BIOS settings.

[image]

Comment: If it solves your problem, click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "I accept the answer

Comment: Both of them enabled yet i had to set Trusted Execution to Off .. Thanks for bios tip..

Comment: On my Asus motherboard, this option is called **"Intel (VMX) Virtualization Technology"**. Enabling it made Virtualbox show the 64-bit options.