# Win 10 64/ vb with ununtu 64 installed need 64bit vb on system

Tags: virtualbox

I have win10 64 and using vb installed ubuntu 64 I want to install vb on ubuntu 64 but when I do I don't have 64 bit option on virtual box

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the `Hyper-V` that was enabled (`turn windows features on/off`). I.e. you have to disable it (both can't work together as it seems).
Check this question/answer here:

[Why does virtualbox only have 32-bit option, no 64-bit option on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7)

```
If VirtualBox is only showing 32 bit versions in the Version list make sure:
Your Host OS is 64-bits
Intel Virtualization Technology and VT-d are both enabled in the BIOS
The Hyper-V platform is disabled in your Windows Feature list.
```

Also, more details as to 'why':
[Virtualbox has no 64-bit options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675251/virtualbox-has-no-64-bit-options)

This is more of a summary (as Q/A on this are not that specific) and Hyper-V seems like the most common problem (virtualization is most often enable already, and you probably know what type of system you're running).

**EDIT**: **this is not the answer to OP troubles, once he described what he actually wants, but I'm leaving it as it is for now**.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 64bit on vb and now on Ubuntu vb installation 64 bit not showing

Comment: you mean you're trying to install virtualbox within VM within VirtualBox? But why? Just install it in your original Win10 VirtualBox. 
And you do need to be more specific with your question (describe things better).

Comment: And as to `why` that might not work - my guess is that Ubuntu VM doesn't have virtualization enabled (for some reason, drivers or whatever), i.e. it can't be the "host", or is clashing with the VirtualBox upstream. Anyways, that seems like a really bad idea, I'd be surprised if that works.