# Ubuntu 13.10 : VirtualBox crash problem

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox, login, ram, crash

I have VM running with following configurations:

**RAM : 1000MB

Video Memory : 128MB

Enabled : 3D accleration

Guest OS : Ubuntu 13.10 (guest additions)**

However my ubuntu is not working fine. 
I login VirtualBox crashes.

If I decrease **RAM to 512MB**, I get **login loops**. **Over 1.5GB** Virtual box always **crashes**.

Host System spects :

**Intel core i5 @ 2.4GHz quad core,

6GB RAM,

1.6GB Intel HD Graphic 3000,

Windows 7 Home Premium x64**

Please tell me what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply..... here are my system spects : **Intel core i5 @ 2..4GHz quad core, 6GB RAM, 1.6GB Intel HD Graphic 3000, Windows 7 Home Premium x64**

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a short guide on what to do first when a fresh Ubuntu installation crashes in Virtual Box:

- Make sure you had enabled [VT-x/AMD-V in BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox).
- Leave some CPU power for the host (if all cores were assigned, define an execution cap).
- Leave enough RAM for the host OS (how much depends on the OS and applications running).
- [Install the guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox).
- Update your guest Ubuntu for bugfixes:

  1. Boot Ubuntu to the login screen.
  2. Press <kbd>HOST</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> for a terminal.
     <sub>(alternatively to 1.- 2. we may also [boot to a root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) with networking. Then no sudo is needed for commands below)</sub>
  3. Type the following commands:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
     ```
  4. Enter your password (nothing is displayed!).
  5. Answer `Y` to download and install updates & bugfixes.
  6. After done type `reboot`.
  7. In case [dkms](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dkms) [image: Install dkms] was not installed in the guest we will have to re-install the guest additions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was able to solve it by disabling 3D acceleration for the VirtualBox guest.

Comment: Please explain, how to do that (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: The settings are easy to find in the VirtualBox host UI: Settings -> Display -> Enable 3D Acceleration