# Ubuntu 14.04 as guest in Windows 7 VirtualBox: error occurs after installing guest additions

Tags: virtualbox

I've tried several times now to install Ubuntua 14.04 as a guest OS in a Windows 7 VirtualBox host, and the first sign that something goes wrong is an "internal error" that Ubuntu first reports after I install the guest additions, followed later by a failure when booting Ubuntu (VirtualBox crashes).

The error I'm getting is as follows (note: this first occurs after installing the guest additions) (second note: it mentions some packages are obsolete.

1. does that sound like the real reason?
2. how do I upgrade these packages? [sorry for my Linux newbieish])

Errors:

```
Sorry Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error.

ExecutablePath

  /usr/lib/libgnome-desktop-3-7/check_gl_texture_size

Package

   libgnome-desktop-3-7 3.8.4-0ubuntu3

Problem Type

   Crash

Title

   check_gl_texture_size crashed with SIGSEGV

ApportVersion

   2.14.1-0ubuntu3

Arhitecture

   i386

CoreDump

    (binary data)

Date

   <today's date>

Dependencies

   <very long list>

Disassembly

   #0 0xb71e9120 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri_so
   No symbol table info available.
   Connot access memory at address 0x592a8c15

DistroRelease

   Ubuntu 14.04

Installation Media

   Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release i386 (20140417)

PackageArchitecture

   i386

ProcCmdLine

   /usr/lib/libgnome-desktop-3-7/check_gl_texture_size

.. skipping some stuff ..

SegvAnalysis

   Failure: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'symbol'

Signal

   11

UnreportableReason


   You have some obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade

   dpkg, initramfs-tools, initramfs-tools-bin, libelf1, libfreetype6, libguddev-1.0-0, libjbig0, libpam-systemd, libselinux1, libsystemd-daemon0, libsystemd-login0, libtiff5, libudev1, systemd-services, udev

UpgradeStatus

   No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)

UserGroup

    adm cdrom dip lpadmin plugdev sambashare sudo
```

Comment: just reinstall `libgnome-desktop-3-7` package by running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgnome-desktop-3-7` on tty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not unusual that a new Ubuntu release and Virtual Box versions need their time to get used to each other, i.e. to get bugs fixed. This is a process on both sides. Therfeore you will have to upgrade both, Ubuntu, and Virtual Box in the hope that one or the other bugs were fixed.

See my answers to the following questions on how to do that from the command line and what other troubleshooting measures may be worth a try:

- [Ubuntu 13.10 : VirtualBox crash problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391722/ubuntu-13-10-virtualbox-crash-problem)
- [Trouble with Ubuntu installation in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295222/trouble-with-ubuntu-installation-in-virtualbox)