# Virtual box intel vt-x error

Tags: virtualbox

I tried to access the acceleration tap under system under settings and I can not. The tab is greyed out like their is no data available.

Comment: Only if your CPU (which?) supports VT-x/AMD-V you need to make sure you had [enabled it in BIOS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox/256853#256853). Some older CPUs (e.g. some Core2 Duo, Atom, etc.) may not support this.

Answer (score 0):

If the corresponding Virtual Machine is running then the options under acceleration tab(Settings->System->Acceleration) would be grayed out.

So poweroff the virtual machine in-order to enable Hardware Virtualization(*intel vt-x*).

Comment: the machine is powered off but the tab is still greyed out. my processor does not support vt-x

Comment: did you enable  intel virtualization technology in bios?

Comment: My processor doe not have it neither does my computer

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: it depends on the graphic card of your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have :-

1. VirtualBox's error - something likes " VT-X is not available".
2. Host os is 64 bits with more than 4 GB of ram.
3. Guest os is 32 bits

Lest's try to reduce VirtualBox's base memory to be under 4 GB.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: Setting -> System -> Motherboard @Base Memory...