# Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox in Windows 7 runs at 100% CPU and very slowly

Tags: virtualbox

I know it's been asked why Ubuntu is slow as a guest OS in VirtualBox, but all those answers are fairly old and seem to focus on graphics. In my case booting is also very slow, and there is a long delay when launching the software center (or anything) during which time the CPU runs at 100% but nothing is happening graphically. I've given the guest 2 GB of ram, 16 GB of disk space, enabled 3D acceleration (doesn't seem to make a different either way, though), gave it 1 CPU (I wasn't allowed to select more). Shutdown is also slow.

Comment: Did you turn Hardware Virtualization on in BIOS/EFI?

Comment: that was it, didn't turn on Hardware Virtualization. Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it correct? Maybe it seems like an obvious thing, but it's amazing that I couldn't find any reference to it among all these posts about slow systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These symptoms (especially inability to select more than 1 CPU) witness that [Hardware Virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_virtualization) is not turned on.

To turn it on, you need to go into BIOS/EFI. The setting is located under *Advanced Settings/Configuration → CPU Configuration → Intel Virtualization Technology*. See also
[How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)

Also, you need to [install Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) for your system to function properly.

And if none of the above did work, you have to [submit a bugreport](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker).

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem

Host: Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit),
Guest: Windows 7 (64-bit)

Even with the virtualization turned on in host BIOS the CPU load was constantly around **40-50%** in guest idle state

What helped me was **installing Guest Addition with Direct 3D support** (you need to do that in safe mode) and turning on the host **I/O Cache** of the SATA controller

So my current settings are:

**System**

Base memory: **4096 Mb** (8192 Mb total host memory)

Processor: **6 CPUs** (of host 6 CPUs)

PAE/NX: **Enabled**

VT-x/AMD-V: **Enabled**

Nested Paging: **Enabled**

**Display**

Video memory: **128 Mb**

3D Acceleration: **Enabled**

2D Acceleration: **Enabled**

Works like a charm! Virtual Box Version: 4.3.18_Ubuntu r96516