# how to install kali linux in virtualbox in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS . I'm facing problem while installing Kali Linux 64-bit in Virtualbox . When I tried to install Kali ,the virtualbox shows me the below message in the screenshot i have shared . If anyone knows how to solve this problem please help me !

Thanks in advance[image: the message that shows virtualbox while installing Kali linux]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it says "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS"... so go into your BIOS and enable VT-x?

Doing that varies in the different BIOS'es, for more info google your specific computer, and/or with "VT-x is disabled in the BIOS"