# Cannot virtualize 64bit vagrant boxes

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, intel, vagrant

I run Ubuntu 14.04. My CPU is Intel Core 2 Duo CPU P7450. It supports neither VT-x nor EPT. But it is 64bit.

I can only virtualize 32bit boxes with success. When I try 64bit i get a never-ending

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Tried to start the VM from GUI, and I took only this clue:

[image]

I pressed "Continue" and nothing happened but a black empty screen. Any solution? Why cannot I run 64bit VMs with a 64bit CPU???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason we can not run a 64-bit guest in Virtual Box even when run on a 64-bit host is that 64-bit guests don't make use of software virtualization. They depend on hardware virtualization to work:

> VirtualBox's 64-bit guest support (added with version 2.0) and multiprocessing (SMP, added with version 3.0) both require hardware virtualization to be enabled.<sup>[Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt)</sup>

In case our CPU supports it we need to enable it in the BIOS of our computer:

- [How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)

In case our CPU does not support hardware virtualization we are unable to run 64-bit guests. We will still be able to install and run 32-bit guests.

Answer (score 0):

I created a LAMP box to accommodate PC's that don't have VT-x or AMD-v visualization technology. It's currently in the Hashicorp catalog. just change the config.vm.box to teknology/rush-box-32bit.