# Virtual Box Only Allows 32 bit Operating Systems

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit and I try to install Windows 10 64 bit using Virtual Box. My problem is that is only allowing 32 bit options in the list. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your Ubuntu 64-bit?

Comment: @lamino Yes it is. I included that in my question too.

Comment: Make sure you download the AMD64 version from the [official website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

Comment: @lamino Of course I downloaded the correct version I am not a newbie.

Comment: **Make sure that you have virtualization enabled in the BIOS.**

Comment: @Adam I retracted my duplicate vote after you edited your question, because it is indeed not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/575466/cannot-virtualize-64bit-vagrant-boxes and https://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/cannot-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-due-to-this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu and https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox