# Is there anything that can let me run 64bit binary executable files?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, executable, execute-command, emulation

Is there anything in ubuntu 32 bit 14.04LTS something light, that will let me execute 64 bit binary executable files?

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              4988.76
Virtualisation:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

Comment: Which binary file  you are trying to install? Also post the output of `lscpu `.

Comment: I was not talking about dpkg fie, sighs! but edited lscpu.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to run a 64-bit program in a 32-bit OS.  Try a Live CD or USB with a 64-bit version of the OS (assuming your hardware is 64-bit capable, but it most likely is unless it's old or a low-end netbook).

Answer (score 2):

If **and only if** your CPU is capable of [hardware virtualization (VT-x/AMD-V)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox) you can execute a 64-bit application in a virtual 64-bit OS running in a virtual machine such as Virtual Box. Of course this may not be the lightweight solution you need.

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your CPU architecture. If you have a 32 bit CPU, no piece of software is going to allow you to run 64 bit applications because the CPU itself is incapable of running the software.

If you have a 64 bit CPU you are able to run 32 & 64 bit Ubuntu - but only 64 bit Ubuntu can run 64 bit software (AFAIK - I'll keep looking around a bit more). You can also run 32 bit software within 64 bit Ubuntu - it'll just require some of the 32 bit libraries.

One way you can tell if you've got a 32 bit or 64 bit CPU is by running `grep --color=always -iw lm /proc/cpuinfo` in Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). If it returns `lm` (**L**ong **M**ode) as one of the flags, you've got a 64 bit CPU. 
<sub>[cc Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#How_to_Check).</sub>

You can see in this screenshot of my terminal on my laptop with a 32 bit CPU that nothing is returned for that command:

[image]

For a more in depth explanation of the difference between 32 and 64 bit software and Ubuntu, read [this Ubuntu Community Help Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit).