# VirtualBox - Error with ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: virtualbox

[image]

I installed VirtualBox from Ubuntu Software Center, I installed GenyMotion and downloaded a virtual device. When I run it, I get this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: To enable vt-x also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 2):

VT-X is hardware support for virtualization.  You have to enable the VT-X instruction set in your BIOS first before virtualization (running VMs) will work.

If you have a laptop, there may be some issues.  I have an Acer laptop that has VT-X permanently disabled with no option to turn it on, and I know the CPU supports it.

Alternatively, if you are unable to switch your VT-x on, open Virtualbox, click the VM you have, click settings.  On the left side, in the menu where there are categories listed "General, System, Display, Storage, etc." Click on System.  You should see three tabs there, Motherboard, Processor and Acceleration.

Click on the Acceleration tab and uncheck the checkbox that says "Enable VT-x/AMD-V".

Comment: +1 for a good a good and clean answer, very basic knowledge