# Installing Ubuntu 15.10 in a virtual machine under Windows 10-1511 with AMD processor 64-bit

Tags: 15.10

While installing Ubuntu 15.10 under Windows 10, 1511 in a laptop with AMD 64-bit processor got following error message.

```
AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED)
```

How to proceed from there?

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 2):

'AMD-V' represents hardware support for Virtualisation when using an AMD CPU. There could be 3 possible reasons for the lack of AMD-V support:

1. You have it turned off in the Virtual Machine settings (in VirtualBox this setting is under System --> Acceleration --> Hardware Virtualization). See screenshot below for a screen grab of the location...

[image]

2. The setting is turned off in your computer's BIOS. To rectify this you will need to access your BIOS settings and turn it on. Carefully :).
3. If the above settings are not an issue and you are running a Windows host the problem can sometimes be interference from another hypervisor (like Microsoft’s Hyper-V) using AMD-V. Hyper-V can be inactivated by un-checking its box following this sequence:

   ```
    (Windows key + x) --> Control Panel --> Programs -->
    Turn Windows Features on or off --> Hyper-V
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks andrew.46. But still I am unable to reach the deactivated "Acceleration" drop down menu as the Bios wouldn't allow changes.

Comment: How to tackle possibility 3 - interference from another hypervisor to alter acceleration?

Comment: You can turn Hyper V 'on' and 'off' under Windows 10 by accessing the Control Panel (Windows key + x) --> Programs --> Turn Windows Features on or off --> Hyper-V. Give me a little while and I will add this information to my main post...

Comment: Done! Although I suspect that the BIOS issue is going to be the problem and this will be difficult to assist with. There are so many different types of BIOS and then BIOS versions etc...

Comment: I learn Windows 10 home doesn't support Hyper-V. Quote:Seems, that Windows 10 Home is not support Hyper-V :-( Look at VirtualBox,

Hyper-V is not a feature that has ever been available in Microsoft's home edition operating systems as far as I can remember.

You'll either need to upgrade to Pro version (appears to be an issue with virtual network adapters with VMware in windows 10 hosts). Need to confirm this- Can anyone confirm.