# Virtual Machine error while starting Windows XP: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS

Tags: 16.04, windows-xp

I've tried to start XP on my Ubuntu 16.04, but I don't know where to find the image.

This is one of the error that gives me:

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
```

Can some help me ?

Comment: For starters, if you want to run virtual machines you should enable VT-x in BIOS setup.

Comment: after this, the machine is "running" giving me a black screen says
FATAL : No bootable medium found ! System halted...
you know this ?

Comment: where can i find an OS file ?

Comment: Officially you are supposed to use your very own installation DVDs... or the images you downloaded from your MSDN subscription. Unofficially I cannot give advice, but you may try to use a search engine looking for <operating system name> ISO. Beware of viruses, trojans and other malware. Note that Windows XP is out of support. You would be better served by Windows 7 32-bit; it runs everything that Windows XP can run in a VM.

Comment: thanks for the help
my ubunty is 64-bit..anyway i've tried to download an win xp iso image, and now it gives me this error:
PXE-T02: Option negotiation failure (file nott found or inaccessible?)
PXE-E3C: TFTP Error - Access Violation
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM
FATAL : Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.

I wish understand all this......

Comment: What virtualization engine are you using?

Comment: Don't know.... @AlexP

Comment: How come you don't know? What program do you use to start a virtual machine?

Comment: you mean ORACLE VIRTUAL BOX ?

Comment: Right. In Virtual Box you define the components of your virtual machine. One of the components is a virtual DVD drive. Make that to use the ISO file containing the operating system to be installed.

Comment: ok it works...now one more question, how do i connect to the internet? it doesn't read my ethernet cable...

Comment: Use your favourite search engine to look for [install Windowx XP on VirtualBox networking](https://www.google.com/search?q=installing+windows+xp+on+virtualbox+networking). Apparently you need to specify a virtual network adapter which is supported by XP.

Comment: let's put it in this way, either if I connect with wifi, or ethernet cable, and attach to NAT , the browser just connects on msn.com and bing.com.....what can I do?

Comment: anyhow you are reallu helpfull @AlexP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/256792/301745)

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer for the sake of completeness from AlexP comments:

> For starters, if you want to run virtual machines you should enable
>   VT-x in BIOS setup.