# Unable to install Windows 7 in VirtualBox Manager in Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to install Windows 7 32 bit in Virtual Box on Ubuntu OS. I am getting error (refer snap)

What needs to be done for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With knowing than Windows error messages usually are not very clear I would suggest you still try to enable the PAE/NX in the virtual machine's system settings.

Of yourse you will only be able to do that in case your host CPU supports this.

[image]

It may also help to [enable VT-x/AMD-V virtualization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox) in the host's BIOS to then also use it in the VM:

[image]

Last not least we should select the appropriate guest OS "Windows 7 (32-bit)" in the General tab of the machine's settings.

[image]

Comment: Sir, I have  Enabled PAE/NX. But the tab of Acceleration is not active in my case.  Also i am not able to change number of cores. Thats also inactive.

Comment: You will have to enable Vt-x/AMD-V **in BIOS** in case your CPU supports this (few don't).

Comment: Unfortunately unable to do it. As many of the BIOS options are not getting highlighted( i cannot select). Dont know how to overcome this issue. I am using ThinkPad T430 laptop. Please guide if you know the solution.

Comment: We can't say more than here: http://amiduos.com/support/knowledge-base/article/enabling-virtualization-in-lenovo-systems

Comment: I already followed these steps. Problem is that the options are not getting selected. I can see the options but cant change its values in BIOS.

Comment: This would be far off an Ubuntu issue. Consider to search/ask on [su].