# 32-bit ISO for Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, iso, 32-bit

Since my computer can't handle an actual disc for some reason, I tried to use VirtualBox to run Ubuntu on Windows. However, I can't use 64-bit ISOs, because VirtualBox is 32-bit. Is there a 32-bit ISO for Ubuntu?

Comment: After [enabling VT-x in BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox/256853?s=1|4.3404#256853) a 32-bit host can run 64-bit guests.

Comment: ^ What Takkat said, though the way you phrased it kinda makes it sound like you installed the 32-bit version of VirtualBox on a 64-bit host.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 32 bit images are still available for all Ubuntu and Ubuntu "flavour" releases. (Although not necessarily for other distros based on Ubuntu - for example KDE Neon is 64 bit only.)

They are a bit harder to find than I remember, though.

You can find torrent links at [Alternative downloads | Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)
and regular downloads for the release you want at [Ubuntu Releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).