# Virtual Box X86_64 not working

Tags: virtualbox

I have virtualbox installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I want to install Arch linux 64-bit on it. But I cannot 64-bit versions of any os I want to run. Please tell me what I have to do. Thank You for your time.

Comment: maybe enable support for virtual machines in bios. [see this](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/enable-virtual-hardware-bios-68364.html).

Comment: be sure that your computer support VT technlogy and that is is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Comment: You said you cannot install any 64bit OS in your Virtual Box. Does that mean you can install 32bit OS?