# Installing oracle VM on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualbox

Trying to install oracle VM on ubuntu on 16.04 ..It keeps erroring our when start oracle VM:

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user. 

kishore@kishore-ThinkPad-T410:/usr/bin$ dpkg --list virtualbox-*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-===========================================================
ii  virtualbox-5.1:i386         5.1.24-117012~Ubun i386               Oracle VM VirtualBox
un  virtualbox-guest-additions- <none>             <none>             (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-modules    <none>             <none>             (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose              <none>             <none>             (no description available)

ishore@kishore-ThinkPad-T410:/usr/bin$ uname -a
Linux kishore-ThinkPad-T410 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

let me know if you need more information

Comment: Why are you installing a 32-bit VB to a 64-bit comp?

Comment: downloaded the oracle 64bit virutal box only ..can u please provide me the steps to uninstall and install from scratch ??

Answer (score 2):

You installed a 32-bit version of VirtualBox. That is wrong for your 64-bit system.

Run

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox-5.1:i386
```

and install the 64-bit version using `dpkg`.

Comment: thanks ..iam not getting that error any more ..when i start oracle vm pops below error :

Comment: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine oracletest.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: So enable Virtualization ion BIOS. https://askubuntu.com/a/256853/167850