# I can't open any virtual machine on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I'm using Ubuntu 17.0.4.

The error code is :

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine windws 7.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Component: ConsoleWrap

Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: Please go to VirtualBox settings and increase RAM size. Also go to your BIOS settings and check `Virtualization` option to be enabled.

Comment: where can i find bios setting ?

Comment: Which machine do you use ? laptop ? PC?

Comment: i'm using  laptop

Comment: Which model do you use ? you can find how to go BIOS settings of your laptop by googling it but in many cases F12 or F2 may be helpful

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304393/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabl ... *conclusion*: set RAM of virtual machine below `3G`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try these ways:

1. Go to your BIOS settings (By pressing F12, F2, F8, or Delete, ... depends on machine).

   And make sure `Virtualization` option (It can be have names like `VT-d` or `AMD-V` or `Intel Virtualization Technology` or `Virtualization` or ...) to be **enabled**. (And if its be disable make it enable)
2. Go to VirtualBox settings >> System >> Motherboard

   And then increase RAM size (For example to 2GB is good).
3. Go to VirtualBox settings >> System >> Acceleration

   And then **Uncheck** the `Enable VT-x/AMD-V` option.

Comment: Why would you disable Enable VT-x/AMD-V?

Comment: The last line is still wrong.

Comment: That answer is wrong. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox

Comment: How was this answer accepted?. **One cannot edit Acceleration settings when it has a saved session.** And the issue says that VBox is not able to start the saved session.

Comment: @JithinPavithran **This is not about a saved session**. And OP had accepted this answer because his session was powered off (as you see in the image). If you have different issue (about saved session), you can ask a new question.

Comment: point 3 solved for me