can't install Ubuntu, error message (VT-x is disabled in bios for all CPU odes )
I can't install Ubuntu, I get an  error message  (VT-x is disabled in bios for all CPU modes )
I tried to install from Virtual Box 7.0, I re-downloaded the file twice and tried to install 3 times, but I get the same message every time.

"VT-x is disabled in bios for all CPU modes" so enable it? https://askubuntu.com/questions/884706/cant-use-vm-virtualbox-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-all-cpu-modes  https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox   https://askubuntu.com/questions/948171/i-cant-open-any-virtual-machine-on-virtualbox   https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox  to list 4.
