# I can't run Linux-64 Bit on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have a 64-Bit computer and I am thinking about upgrading it to a 64-bit verson I am trying it out on virtualbox first but i get this error.

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Linux Mint-64.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: Please enable `VT-X` in `BIOS` to use Virtualbox!

Comment: Are you trying to run a 64 bit virtual machine on a 32 bit OS?

Comment: OP says 64bit computer @ubfan1

Comment: Did you install 32bit Ubuntu before 'testing' 64-bit?  If you did, you can't run a 64bit VM - you're limited by the 32bit architecture of the OS (not the system)>

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen if the OP is on a 32-bit OS they can't test run the 64-bit OS in a VM, because of system limitations by the OS and not the hardware itself.

Comment: I noticed you mentioned "Mint" here, are you using Mint or actual Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I know @ThomasWard but I saw `64bit computer`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I saw that too, but 64-bit ***hardware*** and 32-bit ***OS*** are different, and the OS will limit the VM if it's 32bit.  Hence why I asked what they're using.

Comment: Thanks. I am using 32-Bit OS thats probably the problem. I am using Linux Mint 32-Bit 17.2.3 I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)

Comment: The answer provided doesn't work. The  BIOS still rejects it even though system virtualization is enabled. How do I fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Use these steps to enable `VT-X` in `BIOS`:

1. Reboot the computer and open the system's BIOS menu. This can usually be done by pressing the delete key, the F1 key or Alt and F4 keys depending on the system.
2. Select Restore Defaults or Restore Optimized Defaults, and then select Save & Exit.
3. Power off the machine and disconnect the power supply.
4. Enabling the virtualization extensions in BIOS:

   a. Power on the machine and open the BIOS (as per Step 1).

   b. Open the Processor submenu The processor settings menu may be hidden in the Chipset, Advanced CPU Configuration or Northbridge.

   c. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT) or AMD-V depending on the brand of the processor. The virtualization extensions may be labeled Virtualization Extensions, Vanderpool or various other names depending on the OEM and system BIOS.

   d. Enable Intel VTd or AMD IOMMU, if the options are available. Intel VTd and AMD IOMMU are used for PCI passthrough.

   e. Select Save & Exit.
5. Power off the machine and disconnect the power supply.
6. Run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "vmx|svm"`. If the command outputs, the virtualization extensions are now enabled. If there is no output your system may not have the virtualization extensions or the correct BIOS setting enabled.

Source:

https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html

Comment: I used to run Windows 7 Ultimate 64-Bit but during a drive wipe I lost the OS and MBR so the recovery disk was worthless. I use a lenovo X300 and sometimes these older systems are a bit "resistant" to some changes you would like to make. Once I was downloading Window 10 onto my desktop which runs on Windows XP Media Center Edition and it saw what i was doing so it stopped the download and said "Permission Denied"

Comment: Just adding to what I just said the BIOS on my computer recieved its last update in January 2009, so I am not sure if thats an option.