# VirtualBox Guest Additions installation 'loop' Ubuntu 18.04 - can't progress!

Tags: virtualbox

Memory failing! I had VB working fine on 16.04 but I'll be blowed if I can remember how I did it!

I have searched for similar questions but the answers all appear to be for different OS's

```
Host - Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.
VirtualBox 5.2.10 (installed using Ubuntu Software centre).
Guest - Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop.
```

I've added my username to the vboxusers group.

I 'insert' the Guest Additions CD and at the pop-up I click on Run

Terminal window opens and all I get is -

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.2.10 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.2.10 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions 
kernel modules.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced 
until the system is restarted
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
Press Return to close this window...
```

Not worried about clipboard etc. - all I want is to use USB memory stick.

Dummy help please 'cause I've no idea what to do next!

Tim

Comment: It is a bit unclear what your actual error is. Can you run the VM after you had installed the guest additions? Any errors you get from the USB-stick? Where [on this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/25600/3940) are you stuck?

Comment: The output you list is normal, so no one can hep you unless you explain the problem you are having.

Comment: @Takkat I got quite excited as I hadn't come across that tutorial but I'm now more unsure how to proceed as current VM version seems not to support i386.  As for my problem - I can't figure how to set a USB filter.

Comment: @TimSilver: it does suppor 32-bit (i386) (tell it on creating a VM in the general setting / version )  but for 64-bit guests (am64) you'd want to enable [hardware virtualization in BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox).

Comment: If you had installed an extension pack from Oracle, you will have to do that again after the host upgrade (it may be the missing step you can't remember)