# Virtualbox vm of IE11 on Win7 / 8.1 / 10 keep crashing

Tags: 14.04, windows, virtualbox, virtualization, ie

I'm trying to get the famous virtual machines of Microsoft up and running. More specifically those with IE11 on them (so that's the Win7, Win8.1 and Win10 version).

From what I can read on the web this should be a cakewalk. Currently all of them crash during start up (taking a varying amount of time).

PC setup :

- Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 3.19.0-30-generic)
- Virtualbox (5.0.10r104061): had some issues to get it up & running (Fixed by following: [VirtualBox 5.0 installation has broken VirtualBox packages on Kubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666026/virtualbox-5-0-installation-has-broken-virtualbox-packages-on-kubuntu-15-04/666039#666039))

Virtualbox actions:

- I followed [IE 7/8/9/10/11 Virtual machines from Microsoft](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/5274656) to get the necessary files.
- To get a VM running I went from **New** (this drops you in "*Create Virtual Machine*") and followed the various steps. In step 3 I selected the option to "Use an existing virtual hard disk file" and pointed it to the vmdk file I had gotten earlier.
- There are various "error" entries in the VBox logs, but Google isn't helping me to find out what is going wrong / how to fix it:

  - [IE11 Win7](http://pastebin.com/VRq5GBa3)
  - [IE11 Win8.1](http://pastebin.com/BkfGTWN4)
  - [IE11 Win10](http://pastebin.com/mwLPv86c)
- Hardware acceleration is enabled (following pcapademic's answer for [How to determine if CPU VT extensions are enabled in bios?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103965/how-to-determine-if-cpu-vt-extensions-enabled-in-bios/103966#103966).

I'm certain that I haven't checked everything, but due to having zero experience with using Virtualbox, I have no idea what the next logical step is. A helpful pointer would be appreciated.

---

dkms of Virtualbox:

```
vboxhost, 5.0.10, 3.19.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
vboxhost, 5.0.10, 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
3.19.0-33-generic
vboxpci                24576  0 
vboxnetadp             28672  0 
vboxnetflt             28672  0 
vboxdrv               450560  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
```

VBoxManage showvminfo:

- [IE11 Win7](http://pastebin.com/b19NdeZW)

---

We still have an issues remaining for the Win10 VM:

- [VBoxManage showvminfo IE11 - Win10](http://pastebin.com/5Qf2XM5c)
- [VBox log IE11 Win10](http://pastebin.com/CxhmmKar)

---

Additional issue on Win10 VM:

- Encountered an 0xc0000605 on the Win10 machine
- Solution: this is related to the time change that you need to do. If I set my time on the Host machine **between 01/04/2015 and 15/04/2015** then everything is fine.

Comment: Have you installed the Virtualbox Additions? If so, try to uninstall them and restart your VMs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried IE11-Win7 in Ubuntu 15.10 with same VM version as yours (5.0.10r104061). It boots up well. I'm not familiar with VBox log, but i noticed hard drive errors in all the 3 machines you have.

Your virtualbox host drivers (kernel modules) built well (`dkms status`) and loaded (`lsmod|grep vbox`)

From your [`ls -l`](http://pastebin.com/4fYksHUS) output  & [`VBoxManage showvminfo "IE11 - Win7" --details`](http://pastebin.com/b19NdeZW) output , quiet different setup.

A quick thought may be you haven't used the VirtualBox ***import*** function. It seems like you make manual HDD image setup:

- Yours is SATA, mine is IDE.
- I've new `.vmdk` image created in the VM folder, but you don't have any.

So the correct way is to use the import function of VB to create new virtual machine from a VirtualBox archive.

1. Move the original files to another folder out of `/home/gco/VirtualBox VMs/` example to `~/vm/ie11win7`, not a must but clean way to keep `VirtualBox VMs` only for running machine images.
2. Open virtual box then delete the old "IE11 - Win7"
3. From Menu, *File* → *Import Appliance...*
4. Browse to `.ovf` or `.ova` file & select it.
5. *Next*, then *Import* (without changing anything, you can change it later).

Then Try launch.

BTW, last step from [README.md](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/5274656), that extract `.ova`, is not needed, VirtualBox can import the archive directly.

I will tell original author to remove extract `.ova` step add an `import` step to the instructions. That should help the coming users.

```
VBoxManage import "IE11 - Win7.ova"
```

**Reference:** [8.10. VBoxManage import](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-import)

Concerning the crashing IE11-Win10, I got this error in the [uploaded screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viCTE.png)

> ```
> Recovery
>
> Your PC/device needs to repaired
> The digital signature for this file couldn't be verified.
>
> File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
> Error code: 0xc0000428
> ```

Solved by changing my host machine time to before April 15.

**Sources:**

- [ModernIE VM Windows 10 for Parallels won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130229/modernie-vm-windows-10-for-parallels-wont-run)
- [Bug report: Problem with Windows 10 on WIndows 7 Virtual Box](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1326730/problem-with-windows-10-on-windows-7-virtual-box)